# Convert nested list comprehension to use itertools chain in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension, python-itertools

Inspired by the discussion in [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) I tried to convert this (getting files and folders modification times in some_directory):

```
c = [os.path.getmtime(item) for root, d, files in os.walk(some_directory)
        for item in [root] + map(lambda fi: os.path.join(root, fi), files)]
```

To use itertools.chain:

```
c = map(os.path.getmtime,
        itertools.chain.from_iterable([root] + map(lambda fi: join(root, fi), files)
                                      for root, d, files in os.walk(some_directory)))
```

but my profiling shows it to be slower plus does not look really elegant.

So how can I use chain in this case, that is how can I more elegantly (and faster) produce the intermediate lists ?

Or is there some other itertools function for my case ?

EDIT:

Hashed up a profiling script:

```
import timeit

repeat = 10

setup ="""
import itertools
import os

join = os.path.join
path = r'C:\Dropbox\eclipse_workspaces'
c = []
"""


print "Original             ", min(timeit.Timer("""[c.extend([join(root,dir) for dir in dirs] + [join(root,file) for file in files]) for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path)]""",
                       setup=setup).repeat(3, repeat))
print "For loop             ", min(timeit.Timer("""for root, d, files in os.walk(path):
    c.append(root)
    c.extend(join(root, fi) for fi in files)""",
                       setup=setup).repeat(3, repeat))
print "Comprehension        ", min(timeit.Timer('[item for r, d, f in os.walk(path) for item in [r] + map(lambda f: join(r, f), f)]',
                       setup=setup).repeat(3, repeat))
print "Comprehension + chain", min(timeit.Timer('[item for r, d, f in os.walk(path) for item in itertools.chain.from_iterable(([r], map(lambda fi: join(r, fi), f)))]',
                       setup=setup).repeat(3, repeat))
print "Itertools            ", min(timeit.Timer("""[j for j in itertools.chain.from_iterable([root] + map(lambda fi: join(root, fi), files)
                                      for root, d, files in os.walk(path))]""",
                       setup=setup).repeat(3, repeat))
```

seems there is no difference but I had some strange artifacts when profiling so I don't post any results. I am still interested in the fastest way that can be done, preferably using itertools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it makes sense to use `chain` here. `chain` is most useful when flattening is the whole point of the comprehension it's replacing. If you're doing more complicated stuff, then it's probably easier just to stick with a comprehension or generator expression. Or even unpack the structure into an explicit for loop, which might allow you to avoid things like the list concatenation in your current code:

```
c = []
for root, d, files in os.walk(some_directory):
    c.append(root)
    c.extend(join(root, fi) for fi in files)
```

Comment: Thanks - I can also avoid list concatenation by some horrid thing like `itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[root], map(lambda fi: join(root, fi), files)]
                                      for root, d, files in os.walk(path)))` - I feel I miss something in itertools notation - could you rewrite my sample avoiding the `for root, d, files ....` ?

Comment: Yeah, you could use an extra `chain` call to avoid the concatenation, but it will be ugly. I don't think there's any elegant way to use `chain` with the output of `os.walk`. They just don't go well together. When you want the `root` name as well as the files, it's even worse.